# Как обработать событие нажатия на раскрытие списка в TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Решил переписать программу из прошлых вопросов (если кто в теме).

Так вот, у меня есть список `TreeView` с большой вложенностью и я хочу, чтобы, при нажатии на раскрытие любого из элементов этого дерева ("+"), вызывалась определенная функция, которую я сам напишу. Как это реализовать?

Дело в том, что мне нужно отобразить очень много элементов и моя программа тормозит и долго открывается. Я хочу чтобы элементы динамически подгружались при раскрытии списка. И еще. Пока я не добавил элементы, плюсик отображаться не будет. А мне нужно, чтобы он отображался и только, когда пользователь нажмет на него, элементы списка (ключи реестра) подгрузились.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, как видите, плюсиков нет.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforeexpand?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Bulson это первая ссылка, которую мне выдал поисковик. Но если бы мне это помогло, я бы не задавал вопрос тут :)

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю в чем проблема. Дерево не раскрывается при нажатии на плюсик или события не происходит?

Comment: посмотрите на полный пример https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.checkboxes?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Bulson ну как минимум у меня `checkForCheckedChildren` подчеркивается красным, да и сам код непонятно зачем мне нужен. Мне нужно просто 1) Я нажимаю на плюсик. 2) Выполняется определенная функция. Все. Мне не нужно каких-то готовых функций.

Comment: Чтобы появился плюсик, добавьте в список узлов хотя бы один, фейковый. Потом замените его на настоящий.

Comment: Ситуацию с тормозами можно исправить, [вот решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1182133/373567).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void treeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }
```

И в дизайнере:

```
this.treeView1.BeforeExpand += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewCancelEventHandler(this.treeView1_BeforeExpand);
```

Для появления плюсика, нужно вручную добавить пустые элементы в список, а потом их удалить по мере заполнения настоящими данными.